# Android getView method do not read textView

Tags: android

I have ListAdapter there is getView(); method. This is a code for method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int idx, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.check, null);
    }

    return view;
}
```

And this is check.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:textColor="#615742"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that it reads only checkbox. And it igonres my TextView. If I write in xml file only checkedtextview then text appears but then I can not implement checkbox. What is a problem in my code that it ignores textView and it shows only checkbox?

Comment: I don't see you setting any text into that text view - either in XML or in code.  How do you know that the text view is not present?

Comment: How can I add TextView to getView method();?

Comment: You don't need to add it to getView method - you need to set text into it - see answer by @Robin for an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public View getView(int idx, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.check, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView1);
    tv.setText("XXXXXXXX");
    return view;
}
```